# $\operatorname{Func}(J,Ab)$ has enough injectives.

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

I am trying to show that the functor category $\operatorname{Func}(J,Ab)$ has enough injectives (meaning that for each $F\in \operatorname{Func}(J,Ab)$ there is an injective object $I\in \operatorname{Func}(J,Ab)$ and a monomorphism $F\to I$ in $\operatorname{Func}(J,Ab)$), where $Ab$ is the category of abelian groups and $J$ is the category

$$0\leftarrow 1 \leftarrow 2 \leftarrow \cdots$$

(so $J$ is the opposite of the category associated to the poset of non-negative integers).

($\operatorname{Func}(J,Ab)$ is the category of functors from $J$ to $Ab$, with arrows being natural transformations).

Here is what I was able to do:

I can show that $Ab$ has enough injectives.

I know that a natural transformation $\phi: F\to G$ is a monic arrow in $\operatorname{Func}(J,Ab)$ if and only if $\phi_i:F(i)\to G(i)$ is monic for all $i$.

Given $F\in \operatorname{Func}(J,Ab)$, I can find $I\in \operatorname{Func}(J,Ab)$ and a monomorphism $F\rightarrow I$, where $I(i)$ is injective for all $i$ (I just use the fact that $Ab$ has enough injectives to construct monomorphisms $\phi_i:F(i)\rightarrow I(i)$ with $I(i)$ injective and then use the fact that the $I(i)$ are injective to define $I$ on arrows so that $\phi$ becomes a natural transformation $F\to I$). The problem is that now I can't prove that $I$ is an injective object in $\operatorname{Func}(J,Ab)$:

- Is it true that if all the $I(i)$ are injective in $Ab$ then $I$ is
  injective in $\operatorname{Func}(J,Ab)$?

  (I don't think so, but I didn't find any counterexamples).

I know that if I take an injective object $A\in Ab$ and consider the constant functor $F(i)=A$ for all $i$ and $F(\alpha)=\operatorname{id}_{A}$ for all arrows $\alpha$ in $J$, then $F$ is an injective object in $\operatorname{Func}(J,Ab)$.

I tried using limits:

I know that the functor $\lim:\operatorname{Func}(J,Ab)\to Ab$ is left exact and I used this to show that if $I\in \operatorname{Func}(J,Ab)$ is an injective object then $\lim I\in Ab$ is an injective object.

- Is it true that if $\lim\;I$ is injective then $I$ is injective?

I would be very grateful for any hints.

Comment: One way to do this is to use the general theorem proved by Grothendieck in his Tôhoku paper. This is explained in Weibel's book on homological algebra, for example.

Comment: I think you will find a proof in the first chapters of Gabriel's thesis (Categories abeliennes).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sledgehammer proof. (I have not tried to find an elementary proof.)

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an arbitrary small category, and let $\hat{\mathcal{C}} = [\mathcal{C}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Set}]$ be the presheaf topos on $\mathcal{C}$. The functor category $[\mathcal{C}^\textrm{op}, \textbf{Ab}]$ is equivalent to the category $\textbf{Ab}(\hat{\mathcal{C}})$ of all abelian group objects in $\hat{\mathcal{C}}$, and $\hat{\mathcal{C}}$ is a Grothendieck topos, so $\textbf{Ab}(\hat{\mathcal{C}})$ has enough injectives. (See Johnstone [*Topos Theory*, p. 261], for example.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unforntunately I do not know enough about category theory or topos theory to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the answer to your first question is yes.  Given the $I$ that you constructed, such that each $I(i)$ is injective, then the functor $I$ is injective.  Suppose we have a monic arrow $f: G \hookrightarrow H$ of functors in $Func(J,Ab)$, and suppose we're given an arrow $g: G \rightarrow I$.  Since each $I(i)$ is injective and each $f(i)$ is monic, by the universal property of injective objects there exist $h(i): H(i) \rightarrow I(i)$ extending $g(i)$, i.e. $h(i) \circ f(i)=g(i)$ for each $i$.  These $h(i)$ define a functor $h:H \rightarrow I$ which extends $g$, i.e. $h \circ f=g$, so this verifies the universal property of an injective object.

Comment: The problem I have is with showing that the h(i) define a natural transformation $h:H\to I$. In the meantime, my professor has written a sketch of solution, I will post the solution here as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\A}{\mathscr{A}}\newcommand{\I}{\mathcal{I}}\newcommand{\ev}{\operatorname{ev}}$I sketch one possible proof, which is like what appears in Weibel's book but has a few more details.

Firstly, we recall the following facts from "basic" category theory:

> - A natural transformation of functors is monic in the functor category if and only if every component of the transformation is monic, **assuming** the codomain has all pullbacks - true in particular when the codomain is an Abelian category. (Weibel never mentions this one but they really, really should!)
> - If $L\dashv R$ is some adjunction and $L$ preserves monics, then $R$ preserves injective objects.

Fix an Abelian category $\A$ with enough injectives *and* all products (equivalent to completeness of $\A$) (e.g. this is true for $\A=\mathsf{Ab}$) and fix a small category $\I$.

Claim: for $k\in\I$, the $k$th evaluation $\ev_k:\A^\I\to\A$ is a left adjoint, with right adjoint $k_\ast$ defined by $\I\ni j\mapsto\prod_{\I(j,k)}A\in\A$ and the obvious action on morphisms.

Sketch of proof: the isomorphism $\A^\I(F,k_\ast A)\overset{\cong}{\to}\A(\ev_kF,A)$ is given by taking some natural $\gamma:F\implies k_\ast A$ and sending it to $$\large F(k)\overset{\gamma_k}{\longrightarrow}\prod_{\I(k,k)}A\overset{\pi_{1_k}}{\longrightarrow}A$$

Then, because $\ev_k$ perserves all monics by our first basic fact, our second fact implies that $k_\ast$ preserves all monics.

Fix $F\in\A^\I$. For each $k\in\I$ there is a monic $\iota_k:F(k)\to A_k$ where $A_k$ is injective and these transpose to morphisms $\gamma_k:F\implies k_\ast A_k$; if $E:=\prod_{k\in\I}k_\ast A_k$ then there is an induced $\delta=\langle\gamma_k\rangle_{k\in\I}:F\implies E$. Because each $k_\ast A_k$ is injective, $E$ is injective.

It suffices to show that $\delta$ is monic. Fix $j\in\I$; we need to show $\delta_j:F(j)\to E(j)=\prod_{k\in\I}\prod_{I(j,k)}A_k$ is monic. This follows (why?) if we show its obvious projection to $A_j$ is monic, but this is true because that arrow is precisely $\iota_j$ which is monic is hypothesis.

Thus, $F$ is a subobject of some injective object $E$ in $\A^\I$.